Integral with Rectangle, my result: $1.0785633$ but book: $2.16$
Find Integral using the rectangle method.
$$\int_{-1}^{1} {2^{−x}} \,dx$$
Declaration:
$n=5, $
$\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{1-(-1)}{5}=\frac{2}{5}=0.4$
Midpoints: $0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 1.4, 1.8$
Attempt:
$\int_{-1}^{1} {2^{−x}} \,dx \approx$
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 f(x)\Delta x $
$f(0.2) \times 0.4 +f(0.6)\times 0.4 +f(1)\times 0.4+f(1.4)\times 0.4+f(1.8)\times 0.4$
My result: $1.0785633$
According to the book: $2.16$.
EDIT: Based on comment by Hagen von Eitzen,
$$1.0785633 \times 2 \approx 2.16 (2.1571266)$$
EDIT: The actual error in this calculation was due to the midpoints exceeding the limitation $-1,1$ as pointed by @Zoudelong in the comments section.

Why to choose the midpoints between $[0,2]$?

Yeah, your midpoints should  be in $(-1,1).$

All your function evaluations seem to be one unit too fr to the right. For the function in question, that makes each of your function values exactly half the correct value. Thereby, your final sum is also only half as big as it should be.

@Zoudelong because $\frac{0.4}{2}=0.2$, hence, to my understanding. Correct me if I am wrong.

@HagenvonEitzen yes, so, $\approx Answer \times 2$ yields $2.16$.

@SaraJönsson Instead, you should take $-0.8,-0.4,0,0.4,0.8$, because we are integrating over $[-1,1]$, right?

@Zoudelong Yes. Correct. Thanks a lot.

Proper calculation
$n=5, $
$\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{1-(-1)}{5}=\frac{2}{5}=0.4$
Midpoints: $-0.8, -0.4, 0, 0.4, 0.8$
$\int_{-1}^{1} {2^{−x}} \,dx \approx$
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 f(x)\Delta x $
$f(-0.8) \times 0.4 +f(-0.4)\times 0.4 +f(0)\times 0.4+f(0.4)\times 0.4+f(0.8)\times 0.4$
New result: $\approx 2.16 \, (2.157126599)$
Addendum
Based on comment by @Hagen von Eitzen:

"All your function evaluations seem to be one unit too fr to the
right. For the function in question, that makes each of your function
values exactly half the correct value. Thereby, your final sum is also
only half as big as it should be."

The actual error in this calculation was due to the midpoints exceeding the limitation $\left[-1,1\right] $ as pointed by @Zoudelong.
